# How can I show badge count near text?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to show number in circle in some places, like button. Is there a widget for it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use library called `badges: ^1.1.0`

```
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
```

wrap your child widget like this

```
Badge(
      badgeContent: Text('3'),
      badgeColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      shape: BadgeShape.circle,
      child: yourwidget(),
    );
```

hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

**Simplest way** is to use **`CircularProfileAvatar`** Widget,

it supports `background image` / `color` of your choice, supports caching of image too if you pass any

it supports `onTap` to work as a button

you can pass `radius` as a parameter

```
CircularProfileAvatar(
    initialsText: Text("123"),
    radius: 10.0,
    onTap: (){
      //code here
      //if you want it to do something when user taps on it
    }
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
  Widget textWithBadge(String text, int count) {
    var children = <Widget>[
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(text),
      )
    ];

    if (count > 0) {
      children.add(Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: 24,
        height: 23,
        child: Text(
          count.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 12.0,
          ),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
        ),
      ));
    }

    return SizedBox(
        height: 24,
        width: 200,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: FractionalOffset.topRight,
          children: children,
        ));
  }
```